# Added Alias to .bashrc but no results

Tags: unix, alias, bash

I added an alias (alias homedir='cd /export/home/file/myNmae'
) to .bashrc in my home directory and restarted the session. When I run the alias it says homedir: command not found.

Please advice.

Comment: run alias, is you alias showing?

Comment: i added the following line to the file (alias homedir='cd /export/home/Files/myName') ; but when i do homedir it says command not foun

Comment: should i add it to the .profile file instead?

Comment: So if you run the alias command, what does it return? Adding to .bashrc is fine.

Comment: do you really have your alias definition surrounded by `( ... )` parens? If so, take them off. Good luck.

Comment: @ shelter - in the actual command - i dont have parens :-)

Comment: i get the error -bash: homedir: command not found

Comment: i found the solution - i added it to the .profile file and restarted the session - it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found the solution - i added it to the .profile file and restarted the session - it worked

Answer (score 2):

This is because .bashrc is not sourced everytime, only for interactive non login shells .bashrc is sourced.

From the bash man page.

```
When bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a non-interactive shell with the --login option, it first reads and executes commands from  the  file  /etc/pro-
   file,  if that file exists.  After reading that file, it looks for ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile, in that order, and reads and executes commands from the
   first one that exists and is readable.  The --noprofile option may be used when the shell is started to inhibit this behavior.

   When a login shell exits, bash reads and executes commands from the files ~/.bash_logout and /etc/bash.bash_logout, if the files exists.

   When an interactive shell that is not a login shell is started, bash reads and executes commands from ~/.bashrc, if that file exists.  This may be inhibited by using  the
   --norc option.  The --rcfile file option will force bash to read and execute commands from file instead of ~/.bashrc.
```